# SQL - How to combine (UNION?) 3 columns, while using a WHERE clause on a different column

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, union, where-clause

I'm trying to join 3 email columns from the same table into 1 big email column, of which I can do with this SQL:

```
SELECT email
FROM (
SELECT email
FROM accounts
UNION 
SELECT email2
FROM accounts
UNION 
SELECT email3
FROM accounts
)accounts  WHERE email LIKE '%@%'
```

But I also want to be able to only return rows where a different column from the same table (accountgroup) is = to a particular value. For example, what I thought would work:

```
SELECT email, accountgroup
FROM (

SELECT email, accountgroup
FROM accounts
UNION 
SELECT email2, accountgroup
FROM accounts
UNION 
SELECT email3, accountgroup
FROM accounts
)accounts
WHERE email LIKE  '%@%'
AND accountgroup = 'Vyrav'
```

This second statement does not work as intended though, and only returns 1 row. I think the UNION is merging the rows where the accountgroup column values are the same (which will be all rows).

If I modify the first statement to make the last line like this:

```
)accounts  WHERE email LIKE '%@%' AND accountgroup='Vyrav'
```

It says theres an 'Unkown column 'accountgroup' in 'where clause'

Can anybody advise what I'm doing wrong here, or maybe what I should be doing instead?

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Working fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26529/2/0)

```
SELECT
      EMAIL,
      ACCOUNTGROUP
FROM
      (SELECT
            EMAIL AS EMAIL,
            ACCOUNTGROUP
       FROM
            ACCOUNTS
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
            EMAIL2 AS EMAIL,
            ACCOUNTGROUP
       FROM
            ACCOUNTS
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
            EMAIL3 AS EMAIL,
            ACCOUNTGROUP
       FROM
            ACCOUNTS) ACCOUNT
WHERE
      EMAIL LIKE '%@%'
      AND ACCOUNTGROUP = 'Vyrav';
```

**RESULTS:**

```
EMAIL                     ACCOUNTGROUP             
------------------------- -------------------------
a@a.com                   Vyrav                    
b@b.com                   Vyrav                    
c@c.com                   Vyrav                    

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, 
using that statement I get a syntax error "for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT EMAIL, ACCOUNTGROUP FROM (SELECT EMAIL' at line 14"

Comment: I dont understand. Is it oracle?

Comment: I'm using MySQL version 5.5.30-cll.

Comment: Lol.. ALways say on what flavor... THis is for Oracle

Comment: That's exactly the end result I'm after, but will that be creating a table in my database, that overwrites my current accounts table or data?
Sorry I'm relatively new to SQL - still picking up the basics :)

Comment: check now.. also posted fiddle link

Comment: Thanks for that, it seems to work fine as expected on the fiddlelink, however when in phpMyAdmin it still only returns one row. Confused :S

Comment: Made a tiny change and it worked, thanks a lot for your feedback!

Comment: @user2968514 Remember to 'Accept answer' if this is the solution to your question :)

Comment: Accepting answer and upvoting are more politer than a comment

Comment: heh took me a while to realize the tick was the accept answer button. Had me a bit confused for a while, also can't upvote until I get 15 reputation, sorry about that :(

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, `UNION` will unify identical results. Instead, you should use `UNION ALL` to preserve all the original rows, even if they are identical.